# Eclipse default package import

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a simple Java class that uses the `Scanner` function

When creating the class in Eclipse a default package gets created

```
import java.util.Scanner;       //Scanner built in .. takes input from keyboard

package buckytut6;

public class apples 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(bucky.nextLine());//pause and wait till u get input
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>     at buckytut6.apples.main(apples.java:6)

Can anyone help me with this error please?

Comment: Consider removing numbers from package names and capitalizing your class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, when you name your project all lowercase it will automatically put that package buckytut6 at the top of your code, to get around that try capitalizing the first letter in your project name. Also when you name a class try and put a capital letter in it like appleOne, sometimes you will run into problems if it is all lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

The `package` declaration must precede any `import` statement. In fact it should be the first line in the file:

```
package buckytut6;  // this is first

import java.util.Scanner;
```

As a side note, it is conventional to give a class a name that starts with an uppercase letter (e.g. `Apples`).

Comment: Worth mentioning something about Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the **import** and **package** lines.